# Retreiving multiple images from firebase using Picasso Library and caching them

Tags: android, caching, firebase, picasso, firebase-storage

I am developing an application in which I need to first retrieve all the images from Firebase and then display in an imageview one by one with a gap of 5 seconds. The images most of the time will remain same, So what I want is to cache these images and if the user is offline use the cached images and display in imageview.
But the problem is I only got the following code with Picasso Library in which the image is directly displayed on the imageview

```
Picasso.with(RetreivingImageFirebase.this)
                .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/yavatmalindicatorserver.appspot.com/o/Photos%2F22268?alt=media&token=a71e00eb-c453-4803-80d1-9d769037ab46")
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(mImageView);
```

I need to somehow first save all the images then display it one by one. I have searched similar questions on stack-overflow but none of them are showing correct methods. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [RequestCreator.fetch](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fetch--)

> public void fetch()
>
> Asynchronously fulfills the request without a ImageView or Target.
> This is useful when you want to warm up the cache with an image. Note:
> It is safe to invoke this method from any thread.

E.g.

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .fit()
  .centerCrop()
  .fetch();
```

Comment: After using 'fetch() where is the image stored I mean how to address that image since the return type of fetch() is void

Comment: Picasso manages its own cache. Next time when you try to load the same image URL into an `ImageView`, it will use the cache.

Comment: Use `Picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` to see if cache is being used.

Comment: Sangharsh since I want to retrieve multiple images from firebase after using fetch() what should I use to display those images into an ImageView. This is the main problem which I am not getting

Comment: Fetch all the images in a loop. 
Now use Picasso normally (as you would have used in case of no cache) to show appropriate image in an `ImageView`. Picasso will check its cache before making any network call

Comment: Ok I will try and get back to you whether it's working or not

Comment: Images are saved but I dont think cache is working properly. If the app is on and we disconnect the internet then the cache is working but if I am restarting the app cache is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133360/discussion-between-sangharsh-and-nikesh-patel).